# Array of structs declaration

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to write this C++ function in which I am trying to set each `Sequence` in the array of Sequences, however when I follow the code on debug I notice that the array is not changing. In particular:

```
compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].c = pic.data[i];
compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].times = counter+1;
```

**don't seem to add any new variables to the array, just override the first one.**
I am thinking that the root of the problem is the declaration:

```
CompressedPic compressed;
compressed.data = new Sequence[pic.height * pic.width];
```

This is the portion of the code:

```
struct  Sequence
{
    char c;
    int times;
};

struct  CompressedPic
{
    int height;
    int width;
    Sequence* data;
};

struct  Picture
{
    int height;
    int width;
    char* data;
};

CompressedPic  compressThePicture(Picture  pic) {
    CompressedPic compressed;
    compressed.data = new Sequence[pic.height * pic.width];
    compressed.height = pic.height;
    compressed.width = pic.width;
    int compressedDataCounter=0;

    for(int i=0; i<(pic.height * pic.width)-1; i++)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while(pic.data[i] == pic.data[i+1]) 
        {
            i++;
            counter++;
        }

        compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].c = pic.data[i];
        compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].times = counter+1;
        compressedDataCounter++;
    }
    compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].times = -1;
    return compressed;
}
```

It would be great if someone could figure out why this is happening.

Comment: could you please clarify?

Comment: it is being initialized as if it was a primitive type, such as `int`

Comment: @Steinfeld, Sorry, forget everything I said. I read the code as completely different from what it is.

Comment: @BWG can you please clarify a little more?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change:

```
compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].c = counter+1;
```

to:

```
compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].times = counter+1;
```

So you can change the `.times` member otherwise you will be overriding your .c member.  Right now you are setting `.c` to 'a' for example.  Then you set `.c` to 103 (`counter+1`).  Which is an int and likely with your archetecture the high bytes are aligning with `.c` and setting it to 0 as well.

So `.c` is getting 0'd and `.times` is never set

Comment: Thanks, this fixed some of the weird problem... however the code is still not adding more variables to the array. It is just overriding the first one.

Comment: @Steinfeld In the debugger - have you watched `compressedDataCounter`

Comment: @Steinfeld then it's very odd. `a[x] =7` should always assign 7 to `a[x]` there is something not in the code you posted or something (`.o`s) maybe that aren't getting cleaned up, or I completely missed something.  You look at `compressed.data[compressedDataCounter].*` before the assignment and after and it doesn't change.  No idea.

Comment: I am not doing any `delete` operations yet, might it be the problem?

Am I declaring `compressed.data = new Sequence[pic.height * pic.width];` this properly?